# VLC won't install due to unmet dependencies

Tags: vlc

I'm running Linux Mint 17.3 and I can't install VLC. When I type in

sudo apt-get install vlc

This is the result I get:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1-3~ubuntu14.04.1~c42.ppa1) but it is
>   not going to be installed Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but
>   4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Please post the output of `apt-cache policy` and `apt-cache policy vlc vlc-nox libstdc++6` into the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have APT/Dpkg package version mismatches, it may mean a bad formed `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Check if it uses distro `upstream`. Change all lines like:

```
deb http://tralalala.xxxxxxxx.com/lol ffff main contrib non-free
```

to

```
deb http://tralalala.xxxxxxxx.com/lol upstream main contrib non-free
```

You don't have to change deb-src lines.
After updating the `sources.list` file, run `sudo apt-get update`. Then try installing VLC again.

Answer (score 1):

Install synaptic pachage manager and fix broken packages

1) Add ppa and install vlc

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

2) Or  Check Dependencies and install vlc

```
 sudo apt-cache showpkg vlc
```

to build dependencies

```
 sudo apt-get build-dep vlc
```

then install it

3) you can inslall vlc from package manager